# Move rest of line inside a closed pair?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-auto-pairs

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

input

```
(|)foo
```

then pressing some key combination to get

output

```
(foo)|
```

or

```
(foo|)
```

I know this can be done with the autopairs plugin. In the docs they write that the default binding is M-}. I am using Vim/iTerm2/Mac, and I can't seem to figure out how to use the meta key.

In the autopairs plugin they let you remap another feature which is called Fast Wrap and is used to enclose a line with brackets. As you can understand, this is not exactly what I'm looking for, but even with Fast Wrap, which is mapped to M-e, I was not able to remap it or used it as is.

I googled and tried using the sed command in the terminal to see what the option key is outputting, then I tried to remap this output to M-}. Didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a need of having another mapping at all.

It's enough to press <kbd>%</kbd> once or twice to get on the right "paren". Then <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, brilliant. I wish there was a cheatsheet for vim with all kind of handy stroke combinations like this one.

Comment: @idankor Well, at least, `xp` seems to be in every "Vim tips and tricks" out of there. So "inventing" `x$p` is not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can define another mapping for `<M-e>` mapping in insert mode. `imap <M-e>`  shows that it is mappped to `<C-R>=AutoPairsFastWrap()<CR>`. So you can define another key map for that, for example:

```
inoremap <c-e> <C-R>=AutoPairsFastWrap()<CR>
```

Comment: Actually I found out that another plugin I have, vim-surround, can get me the line-enclosing functionality. But still my question remains for getting text to move inside a closed pair.

Comment: Does the mapping above work or not?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but is lower case 'c' the notation for the ctrl key, as the upper case 'C' is?

Comment: yes, they both they represent `ctrl`. see `:h key-notation` inside Vim or Neovim.